# Applying styles to materialui component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Components/UI/header';
import { Box, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import { ThemeProvider, withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const styles = () => ({
  overrides: {
    'MuiPaper-root': {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: '#345f',
      }

    }
  }
});





export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const classes = this.props;
    return(<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Paper classes={classes.overrides}>
          <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" height={1}>
            <Header />
          </Box>
      </Paper>
    </ThemeProvider>);
  }
}


export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

`[project img link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhm2n.png)

> Im trying to apply a different background color to the paper api component. When i run the code it generates the same base styles.

Comment: Please never post code as a picture.

Comment: You're always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the MUI generated styles or root. This will set your local `<Paper />` component's background

```
const styles = () => ({
  overrides: {
     backgroundColor: '#345f',
  }
});
```